# i want to make Change specified range in vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have vba coding where range of D4:D8 is selected but i want to get range D4:I4 instead of D4:D8.

the code is given below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim r As Range

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 4 Then
        Set r = Target.Offset(-4, 3).Resize(5)
        Worksheets("ADP").Range(r.Address).Value = r.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

any help will be greatly appriciated by word of thanks.

Comment: Here's the [`Range.Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize) documentation. The *second* argument is the *ColumnSize*.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Your code only selects` D4:D8` if `A8` is changed. If `A9` is changed it selects `D5:D9`, etc. Do you always want the range from row 4, or are you trying select the range 4 rows above the current row? That said, to fix your issue change `(5)` to `(,5)`, insert a comma before the `5`.

Comment: what i want to accomplish is...if cell A8 changed then select d4:i4 & if a9 changed select d9:i9...like wise....

Comment: Then make the change I suggested.